# How to give a value in function to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter, var

In my app, settings button are initiating a window, in that window you insert your link and this link need to get back to main function and work with button, which open this link in browser

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 


def validate(P):
    if len(P) == 0:
        return True
elif len(P) <= 10:
    return True
else:
    return False

def validate_en(s):
   pass

def close():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Close window", "Are u sure you want to exit?"):
        web.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   web = Tk()

   web.configure(background = "black")

   web.title("WebSaver")

   web.geometry("600x400")

   web.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

   web.resizable(False, False)

   web.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)

   def main_content():

       web.withdraw()
       main = Toplevel(web)
       main.title("Application")
       main.geometry("800x600")
       main.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
       main.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)
       main.resizable(False, False)

       canvas = Canvas(main,width = "800", height = "600", highlightthickness = 0, bg = 
    "black")
       canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)   

       upper_text = Label(canvas, text= "TEXT", justify = "center", background = 
    "black", foreground = "white", font = "KacstDigital, 20", borderwidth = 2, 
    highlightthickness = 1, highlightbackground = "gray")
       upper_text.pack(padx = 5)


       def link_1():
           pass

       button_1 = Button(canvas, text = "First link", bg = "#293133", fg = "white", font 
  = "KacstDigital, 18", height = 2, width = 15, command = lambda: link_1)
       button_1.place(x = 30, y = 150)
       button_conf_1 = Button(canvas, text = "settings", bg = "#293133", fg = "white", 
  font = "KacstDigital, 7", width = 7, command = configurate_button_1)
       button_conf_1.place(x = 198, y = 203)
    
   def configurate_button_1():
       def close():
           conf.destroy()

       def apply(link):
           if (link.isspace() or link == ""):
               messagebox.showwarning(title = "Error!", message = "Input is null")
           else:
               close()
               return link

       conf = Toplevel(web)
       conf.title("Application")
       conf.geometry("600x100")
       conf.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
       conf.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close)
       conf.resizable(False, False)         

       canvas = Canvas(conf, width = "600", height = "100", highlightthickness = 0, bg = 
"black")
       canvas.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)   

       vcmd = (canvas.register(validate_en), '%s')

       link_text = Label(canvas, text= "Link: ", justify = "center", background = 
"black", foreground = "white", font = "KacstDigital, 12", borderwidth = 2, 
 highlightthickness = 1, highlightbackground = "gray")
       link_text.place(x = 5, y = 10)   

       link_entry = Entry(canvas, bg = "#293133", fg = "white", font = "KacstDigital, 
 14", width = 45, validate = "key", validatecommand = vcmd)
       link_entry.place(x = 78, y = 10)
       link_button = Button(canvas, text = "Confirm changes", bg = "#293133", fg = 
 "white", font = "KacstDigital, 14", height = 1, width = 20, command = lambda: 
 apply(link_entry.get()))
       link_button.place(x = 15, y = 50)
main_content()
web.mainloop()
```

I need help with getting value from link_entry (in conf.button func.) and give this value to main_content to open this link from main_content.
Sorry for this strange option strings, idk how to get them at the right place

Comment: `configurate_button_1` doesn't get called (and therefore `link_entry` doesn't exist) under after `main_content` has already returned, since it's triggered later by the button that `main_content` sets up (it doesn't actually do anything until after the event loop has started).  Whatever you want to do with `link_entry` will need to get done by some other function.

Comment: I'd suggest using a callback function similar to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function If the callback function is defined in `main_content` it would have access to the scope of `main_content` along with any data passed in as arguments